# (ASP.net)I have Logout Link in the home page and on clicking that link I am redirecting user to the login page

Tags: visual-studio-2010

(ASP.net)I have Log out Link in the home page and on clicking that link I am redirecting user to the log in page. When user click on back in browser it redirecting to home page even after log out.
How to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Mark home page controller action with authorize attribute.